Why $\sigma$ wouldn't change under standard Lorentz transformation in Weinberg QFT V1 Ch2

Weinberg defines one particle via state vector $\Psi_{p,\sigma}$ that is eigenvector of four-momentum and a label $\sigma$ to denote all other degrees of freedom. This is physically understandable, however, how do we know that operator corresponding to $\sigma$ would commute with four-momentum operator, is it via Poincar`e algebra that $J^{\mu\nu}$ commutes with $P^{\mu}$?
Before introducing little group, Weinberg has defined standard momentum $k$ and standard Lorentz transformation $L(p)$ via,
$$p^{\mu} = L^{\mu}_{\ \ \ \nu}(p)k^{\nu}\tag{2.5.4}$$
where $L(p)$ is explicitly dependent on $p$ and implicitly on the form of standard momentum, then Weinberg defines the states $\Psi_{p,\sigma}$ via the representation of standard Lorentz transform and states corresponding to standard vector,
$$\Psi_{p,\sigma} = N(p)U(L(p))\Psi_{k,\sigma}\tag{2.5.5}$$
However, here comes my question, for massive case, conventionally, we would choose $k = (M,0,0,0)$ as standard momentum, so the standard Lorentz transformation should contain rotation that brings $k$ parallel to $p$ and boost, but why the index $\sigma$ wouldn't change in (2.5.4), if we merely consider it as eigenstate of $J_{3}$?

p.s As we can see in (2.5.47), the rotation can be represented by $\exp(iJ_{3}\theta)\exp(iJ_{2}\phi)$, so should $\sigma$ change?
